# recursively create groups in netcdf4 file

Tags: python, netcdf

In python using
os.makedirs('./folder1/folder2/folder3/',exist_ok=True)
will create from the parentdir './' all the folders up to folder3

I wonder if the same logic can be applied to netcdf files when creating groups.
I made this wrapper functions that given a root_grp inside a Netcdf4 file will create a child group inside.

```
def create_group(root_group: netCDF4.Group, group_name: str) -> None:
    """
    create_group
    creates a group inside a netcdf file

    Parameters
    ----------
    root_group : netCDF4.Group
        root group, the new group will be a child of this one
    group_name : str
        name of the child group
    """
    _ = root_group.createGroup(group_name)
```

I can the create groups this way.

```
rootgrp = netCDF4.Dataset(path+"test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
_ = root_group.createGroup(group_name)
create_group(rootgrp,'first')

create_group(rootgrp['first'],'second')
```

I was thinking of a way to do it recursively.
is it possible?

I tried in this way

```
rootgrp = netCDF4.Dataset(path+"test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")

path = 'first/second/third'
groups = [grp for grp in path.split('/') if grp != '']
print(groups)
count =0
while count < len(groups):
    current= groups[count]
    rootgrp.createGroup(current)
    print(current)
    rootgrp=rootgrp[current]  
    count+=1
```

But it creates one group /first/second/third instead of 3 nested ones.